# Is there any emulator for Azure data factory ,azure sql db and Synapse DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

In our project, we are migrating data from data lakes (for which we have emulator) to azure sql db and azure synapse using data factory. 
Do we have any emulator for Azure data factory ,azure sql db  and Synapse DB?
We don't want to spend money on Dev effort. Is there any way we can develop it locally?

Similarly for Azure data bricks.

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is an emulator for CosmosDB, but I have never heard about its counterpart for ADF, SQLDB or Synapse (former Azure SQL DW).
To be honest - for DEV environment - **ADF** should be pretty cheap as you will not pay for instance, only for activity.
When it comes to **Azure SQL DB** - you can scale up (when using) and scale down once you finished working with it. Or, alternatively, you can choose SQL serverless, which is much cheaper as you're paying for usage only.
In terms of **Azure Synapse** - the most expensive part is the computing layer, so just remember to stop/start service when needed.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems to be doubling our cost. As we are commercially buildig products, so we still need to have SQL server. Hence paying SQL on premise license for each dev boxes Plus we now need to pay for each cloud transaction. So instead of decreasing cost, our dev cost seems to be increased. Hence we were looking for some emulator. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: For on-prem SQL Server, you can use Developer edition which is very cheap. If you want to leverage Azure SQL databases - use smaller tiers for developer purposes (also cheap). Of course, you need to pay for Dev activity. DEV environment is nothing else but just another environment.